# Kibana Send Test Email fails

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch

I have configured Kibana alert and when i try to send a test mail. It fails with the following error message in the bottom right window alert as shown below.

**Failed to send the test message Error running com.github.mustachejava.codes.DefaultMustache@3b0ac4bc**

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you check Kibana's logs for more details on the error ?

Comment: what type of destination is it? Could you show the `method` and `header information` of the destination?

Comment: The destination type is SNS. there is no method and header info as we just click on send test mail from kibana expanding the Action tab.

Answer (score 0):

After few tries we realized that you need to run the query by clicking on the Run button. This makes the ctx available and Kibana parses the query result to extract the data and send email. If you send the email without running the query it has issues finding the ctx. Hope this helps

[image]